# SASS @debug directive prints two different values from one place for a variable

Tags: css, sass

I'm receiving the following error when compiling scss file to css:

```
Error: src/scss/_custom.scss
Error: Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'.
```

So I put @debug directives above the line causing the error with offending variables calculation.

The @debug directive however prints two values by variable like this

```
src/scss/_custom.scss:346 DEBUG: $font-size-base `1rem`
src/scss/_custom.scss:348 DEBUG: $input-padding-y `0.5rem`
src/scss/_custom.scss:346 DEBUG: $font-size-base `13px`
src/scss/_custom.scss:348 DEBUG: $input-padding-y `0.5rem`
```

I have two separate files which are imported like this:

```
@import "variables" // $font-size-base: 13px;
@import "custom" // $font-size-base: 1rem !default;
```

As I understand it the problem comes from the second printed value that is used in calculation not the fist one.

How it is possible one variable to hold two separate values at one moment?

And how could I be sure that the second imported file overrides the variable value from the first.

Edit:

The full text of  the error is:

```
Error: src/scss/_custom.scss
Error: Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'.
        on line 350 of src/scss/_custom.scss
>> $input-height:                   (($font-size-base * $line-height-base) + ($in
   -----------------------------------^
```

And the full line is:

```
 $input-height:(($font-size-base * $line-height-base) + ($input-padding-y * 2)) !default;
```

@debug of `$line-height-base`

```
src/scss/_custom.scss:347 DEBUG: $line-height-base `1.42857`
```

Comment: Can you paste the code that is doing the actual calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what is happening from your code

```
($input-padding-y * 2)
```

`$input-padding-y` is `0.5rem`

```
($font-size-base * $line-height-base)
```

`$line-height-base` is `1.42857`

Now you've declared `$font-size-base` twice and one of the declarations uses the `!default` keyword. This simply means use this `!default` value for a variable as long as it is not reassigned somewhere else in the stylesheet. Simply put if a variable is defined twice, the one with the `!default` keyword **is not used**

So `$font-size-base` returns `13px`

Therefore the equation is evaluated as

```
$input-height: (  ( 13px * 1.42857 ) + ( 0.5rem * 2 )  )
```

This is why the error complains about `rem` and `px`

I am not sure exactly the importance and intention for each of those values but the problem can be fixed by either

- adding to `!default` to the `$height: 13px`, that way it uses the one with `rem` units,
- removing the `!default` keyword all together and the later declared variable will overwrite the previous one
- using the same unit of measurement for both variables declared

If the same variable is defined twice in two different files, `@debug` can print two different values of the variable if it has not yet come across the **second declaration or reassignment of the variable**

[image]